# mmap and kernel memory

Tags: linux, kernel, mmap

I understand from [mmap() internals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769364/mmap-internals/769423#769423) that a mmap read works by 
- causing a page fault
- copying file data from disk to internal kernel buffer
- mapping the kernel buffer to user space

My questions are:

- What happens to the kernel mapping to the buffer? if it still exists, dont we have a problem here of user application gaining access to kernel memory?
- cant we run out of physical memory this way? I'd assume the kernel needs a minimum amount of physical memory to provide decent level of performance, and if we keep allocating it's buffers to mmapped user space buffer we'd eventually run out of buffers.
- during a write, does the relevant memory gets mapped temporarily to a kernel buffer? if and this is a shared maping, another user process may access and again gain access to what is now kernel memory

Thanks, and sorry if these questions are pretty basic, but I did not find a clear answer.

Comment: Did you read [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) man page? There are several cases.... And it is mostly about [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), not really physical RAM.

Comment: For question 1, checkout out https://www.marcusfolkesson.se/blog/mmap-memory-between-kernel-and-userspace/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a kernel hacker by any means, but this is what I've gathered:

- I'm not entirely sure when it comes to the question of whether the kernel "relinquishes" its mapping to physical memory, since the kernel can access any physical memory it pleases. However, it would obviously be impermissible for the kernel to keep using that physical memory for its own purposes (e.g. as an internal pipe buffer) if user processes can access that memory as well, for the sake of both the user process and for the sake of the kernel. The kernel will simply designate those pages as part of the filesystem cache (if backed by a file) and not mess with them.
- Yes, to the same extent that any process or number of processes can limit the amount of physical memory present for the kernel by requesting lots of resources like pipes. However, the kernel keeps track of how much physical memory is available and will start to page out userland memory to the disk when the remaining amount of physical memory runs low. Kernel memory itself typically should not be paged out to the disk for reasons including performance. Though the nice thing about `mmap()`ed memory backed by  a file is that it's trivial to page out to the disk; no swap space needs to be allocated.
- If you mean a write to available memory mapped to userland virtual address space (i.e. `memcpy()`, not `write()`), no. The whole point of `mmap()` is to map userland virtual address space to physical memory to allow reads and writes without resorting to system calls. Syncs to the disk will be performed directly by the kernel without additional copying to kernel buffers.